# Display All Custom Post Fields and Values, Unless Empty

Tags: post-meta, custom-field

I am looking to grab all of the custom post meta fields for a given post and display them on the page which i have accomplished with the following code.

However I would like to check if( !empty() ) the custom post meta values and not print any that are empty.

Other then that it should be pretty straight forward but I would appreciate the help.

```
<?php
$custom_fields = get_post_custom();
    foreach ( $custom_fields as $field_key => $field_values ) {
        if(!isset($field_values[0])) continue;
        if(in_array($field_key,array("hits","_wp_trash_meta_time","SKU","sub-category-2","sub-category-1","_wp_trash_meta_status","old_price","price","qty","additional_notes","buy_link","customlist1","customlist2","featured","image","images","_edit_lock","_edit_last","_thumbnail_id","_sexybookmarks_permaHash","_sexybookmarks_shortUrl"))) continue;
    foreach ( $field_values as $key => $value )                             
    echo '<li><strong>' . $field_key . ':</strong> ' . $value . '</li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with default PHP functions.

```
// Loop through all fields, grab the content and assign it to a new array
foreach ( get_post_custom() as $custom )
    $new_custom[] = array_shift( $custom );

// Get rid of empty fields
$new_custom = array_filter( $new_custom );
```